# KnockoutJS Knockout Sortable with Foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to know if Comment Format Foreach will work with Knockout Sortable.

I have the following code structure

```
<div>
    <!-- ko foreach: Countries-->
       <div>
          <div>
               <div class="icon-delete"><img></div>
               <div data-bind="text: CountryName"></div>
           </div>
       </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

I tried replacing **foreach** with **sortable** but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use containerless control flow syntax with `sortable`. From their [github](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable)

> You cannot use containerless bindings (comment-based) bindings at the top-level of your template, as the jQuery draggable/sortable functionality needs an element to operate on.

So, you'll need to use a wrapper element.